# Why sometimes right and sometimes wrong after I submit the same code on leetcode

Tags: javascript

[My Submissions for Remove Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swK1R.png)

It always return `Internal Error`, I promise that I did not change any code!

here is me code:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {number}
 */
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    var i = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
        if(nums[j] !== val) {
            var temp = nums[j];
            nums[j] = nums[i];
            nums[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i;
};
```

oh,I forget that...this is the topic:

> Given an array and a value, remove all instances of that value in
>   place and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this in
>   place with constant memory.
>
> The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave
>   beyond the new length.
>
> Example: Given input array nums = [3,2,2,3], val = 3
>
> Your function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of
>   nums being 2.

Comment: In what sense does the code shown remove an element? Shouldn't a function called `removeElement()` actually do so? What is the point of that swap code in the `if` block when `i` and `j` will be equal for all elements before the one that matches `val`?

Comment: It looks like those different results are different test cases that look for elements being removed. But that function doesn’t look like it removed any elements, so it may result in an infinite loop, as long as elements exist. Just a guess.

Comment: How would we know what "Internal error" means? Ask leetcode.

Comment: @Xufox I don't think so. The length of `nums` is fixed and the loop has a fixed number of iteration, which is that length. What the code does is swapping `nums` cells in order to send all those with a value equals to `val` at the end of the array.

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte My thinking was that the test looked something like this: `while(elements.length){removeElement(`…`)}`. This could certainly create an infinite loop.